# SwiftUI - Choose a specific service when I scan a device in Bluetooth

Tags: swift, xcode, bluetooth-lowenergy, swiftui, core-bluetooth

Choose a specific service when I scan a device

I did a program in which I want to scan a device with a specific service (my device is a thermometer "SHT31" and the service is the battery service "UUID: 180F") but when I run this program on my iPhone, it doesn't scan the device. Whereas when "withServices: nil" it scans the device. Do you have a solution?

My code :

```
import CoreBluetooth

 class BLEConnection: NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {
    var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
    var myPeripheral: CBPeripheral!
    let batteryServiceCBUUID = CBUUID(string: "0x180F")

    func startCentralManager() {
        self.centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        switch (central.state) {
           case .unsupported:
            print("BLE is Unsupported")
            break
           case .unauthorized:
            print("BLE is Unauthorized")
            break
           case .unknown:
            print("BLE is Unknown")
            break
           case .resetting:
            print("BLE is Resetting")
            break
           case .poweredOff:
            print("BLE is Powered Off")
            break
           case .poweredOn:
            print("BLE powered on")
            central.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [batteryServiceCBUUID], options: nil)
            break
        @unknown default:
            break
        }
    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        if let pname = peripheral.name {
//            print(pname)

            if pname == "Smart Humigadget" {
                self.centralManager.stopScan()
                self.myPeripheral = peripheral
                self.myPeripheral.delegate = self
                self.centralManager.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
                print("\(pname) is connected")
            }
        }
    }
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        self.myPeripheral.delegate = self
        self.myPeripheral.discoverServices(nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following format (no hex prefix needed)

```
    let batteryServiceCBUUID = CBUUID(string: "180F")
```

Comment: I tried the line you suggested, but it still doesn't scan the device.

Comment: @MxM, this is correct id declaration, are you sure then that your device advertises exactly this service?

Comment: ,I have the file with detailed information about the device: " https://www.sensirion.com/fileadmin/user_upload/customers/sensirion/Dokumente/2_Humidity_Sensors/Sensirion_Humidity_Sensors_SHT3x_Smart-Gadget_User-Guide.pdf  ". When "withServices: nil" it scans the device but when I use CBUUID(string: "180F") or CBUUID(string: "180A") it doesn't scan the device. I find that strange.

Comment: @MxM, maybe this device just don't have name for for battery service and you did not get into `if let pname = peripheral.name {` condition. Did you try just set breakpoint in the first line of callback or add print log right at the beginning?

Comment: I don't think that's possible with my device, thank you very much for your help.